# PRE-2016 Valgrind: Memory still reachable with trivial program using <iostream>

Tags: c++, valgrind

EDIT:
I've voted to close this is it is now incorrect.

In March 2016 Valgrind gained an option "--run-cxx-freeres=<yes|no>" (default is yes). This will call a libstdc++ function to free one-off allocations used for things like iostream. If you are using a post-2016 Valgrind and libstdc++ you will get

```
==9356== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9356==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9356==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 72,704 bytes allocated
==9356==
==9356== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

ORIGINAL POST:

Take the following trivial program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

If I run this using valgrind, I'm told that there are `72,704 bytes in 1 blocks` that are `still reachable`.  There have been extensive discussions on SO about whether or not to worry about still reachable warnings--I'm not concerned about that.  I'd just like to understand how simply *including* a standard library header could cause a still reachable warning, when none of the objects from that library were allocated in the program itself.

Here is the full `valgrind` output:

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes --show-reachable=yes ./ValgrindTest
==27671== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==27671== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==27671== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==27671== Command: ./ValgrindTest
==27671== 
==27671== 
==27671== HEAP SUMMARY:
==27671==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==27671==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 72,704 bytes allocated
==27671== 
==27671== 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==27671==    at 0x4C2AB9D: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:296)
==27671==    by 0x4EC060F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==27671==    by 0x400F305: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:85)
==27671==    by 0x400F3DE: call_init (dl-init.c:52)
==27671==    by 0x400F3DE: _dl_init (dl-init.c:134)
==27671==    by 0x40016E9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so)
==27671== 
==27671== LEAK SUMMARY:
==27671==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27671==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27671==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27671==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==27671==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27671== 
==27671== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==27671== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

And an object dump:

```
$ objdump -d ValgrindTest 

ValgrindTest:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .init:

0000000000400718 <_init>:
  400718:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  40071c:   e8 8b 00 00 00          callq  4007ac <call_gmon_start>
  400721:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  400725:   c3                      retq   

Disassembly of section .plt:

0000000000400730 <_ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev@plt-0x10>:
  400730:   ff 35 ba 08 20 00       pushq  0x2008ba(%rip)        # 600ff0 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x8>
  400736:   ff 25 bc 08 20 00       jmpq   *0x2008bc(%rip)        # 600ff8 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x10>
  40073c:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)

0000000000400740 <_ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev@plt>:
  400740:   ff 25 ba 08 20 00       jmpq   *0x2008ba(%rip)        # 601000 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x18>
  400746:   68 00 00 00 00          pushq  $0x0
  40074b:   e9 e0 ff ff ff          jmpq   400730 <_init+0x18>

0000000000400750 <__libc_start_main@plt>:
  400750:   ff 25 b2 08 20 00       jmpq   *0x2008b2(%rip)        # 601008 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x20>
  400756:   68 01 00 00 00          pushq  $0x1
  40075b:   e9 d0 ff ff ff          jmpq   400730 <_init+0x18>

0000000000400760 <__cxa_atexit@plt>:
  400760:   ff 25 aa 08 20 00       jmpq   *0x2008aa(%rip)        # 601010 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x28>
  400766:   68 02 00 00 00          pushq  $0x2
  40076b:   e9 c0 ff ff ff          jmpq   400730 <_init+0x18>

0000000000400770 <_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev@plt>:
  400770:   ff 25 a2 08 20 00       jmpq   *0x2008a2(%rip)        # 601018 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x30>
  400776:   68 03 00 00 00          pushq  $0x3
  40077b:   e9 b0 ff ff ff          jmpq   400730 <_init+0x18>

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000400780 <_start>:
  400780:   31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
  400782:   49 89 d1                mov    %rdx,%r9
  400785:   5e                      pop    %rsi
  400786:   48 89 e2                mov    %rsp,%rdx
  400789:   48 83 e4 f0             and    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
  40078d:   50                      push   %rax
  40078e:   54                      push   %rsp
  40078f:   49 c7 c0 80 09 40 00    mov    $0x400980,%r8
  400796:   48 c7 c1 f0 08 40 00    mov    $0x4008f0,%rcx
  40079d:   48 c7 c7 90 08 40 00    mov    $0x400890,%rdi
  4007a4:   e8 a7 ff ff ff          callq  400750 <__libc_start_main@plt>
  4007a9:   f4                      hlt    
  4007aa:   90                      nop
  4007ab:   90                      nop

00000000004007ac <call_gmon_start>:
  4007ac:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  4007b0:   48 8b 05 29 08 20 00    mov    0x200829(%rip),%rax        # 600fe0 <_DYNAMIC+0x1f0>
  4007b7:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
  4007ba:   74 02                   je     4007be <call_gmon_start+0x12>
  4007bc:   ff d0                   callq  *%rax
  4007be:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  4007c2:   c3                      retq   
  4007c3:   90                      nop
  4007c4:   90                      nop
  4007c5:   90                      nop
  4007c6:   90                      nop
  4007c7:   90                      nop
  4007c8:   90                      nop
  4007c9:   90                      nop
  4007ca:   90                      nop
  4007cb:   90                      nop
  4007cc:   90                      nop
  4007cd:   90                      nop
  4007ce:   90                      nop
  4007cf:   90                      nop

00000000004007d0 <deregister_tm_clones>:
  4007d0:   b8 37 10 60 00          mov    $0x601037,%eax
  4007d5:   55                      push   %rbp
  4007d6:   48 2d 30 10 60 00       sub    $0x601030,%rax
  4007dc:   48 83 f8 0e             cmp    $0xe,%rax
  4007e0:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4007e3:   77 02                   ja     4007e7 <deregister_tm_clones+0x17>
  4007e5:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  4007e6:   c3                      retq   
  4007e7:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4007ec:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
  4007ef:   74 f4                   je     4007e5 <deregister_tm_clones+0x15>
  4007f1:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  4007f2:   bf 30 10 60 00          mov    $0x601030,%edi
  4007f7:   ff e0                   jmpq   *%rax
  4007f9:   0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)

0000000000400800 <register_tm_clones>:
  400800:   b8 30 10 60 00          mov    $0x601030,%eax
  400805:   55                      push   %rbp
  400806:   48 2d 30 10 60 00       sub    $0x601030,%rax
  40080c:   48 c1 f8 03             sar    $0x3,%rax
  400810:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400813:   48 89 c2                mov    %rax,%rdx
  400816:   48 c1 ea 3f             shr    $0x3f,%rdx
  40081a:   48 01 d0                add    %rdx,%rax
  40081d:   48 d1 f8                sar    %rax
  400820:   75 02                   jne    400824 <register_tm_clones+0x24>
  400822:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  400823:   c3                      retq   
  400824:   ba 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edx
  400829:   48 85 d2                test   %rdx,%rdx
  40082c:   74 f4                   je     400822 <register_tm_clones+0x22>
  40082e:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  40082f:   48 89 c6                mov    %rax,%rsi
  400832:   bf 30 10 60 00          mov    $0x601030,%edi
  400837:   ff e2                   jmpq   *%rdx
  400839:   0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)

0000000000400840 <__do_global_dtors_aux>:
  400840:   80 3d e9 07 20 00 00    cmpb   $0x0,0x2007e9(%rip)        # 601030 <__bss_start>
  400847:   75 11                   jne    40085a <__do_global_dtors_aux+0x1a>
  400849:   55                      push   %rbp
  40084a:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40084d:   e8 7e ff ff ff          callq  4007d0 <deregister_tm_clones>
  400852:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  400853:   c6 05 d6 07 20 00 01    movb   $0x1,0x2007d6(%rip)        # 601030 <__bss_start>
  40085a:   f3 c3                   repz retq 
  40085c:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)

0000000000400860 <frame_dummy>:
  400860:   48 83 3d 80 05 20 00    cmpq   $0x0,0x200580(%rip)        # 600de8 <__JCR_END__>
  400867:   00 
  400868:   74 1e                   je     400888 <frame_dummy+0x28>
  40086a:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  40086f:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
  400872:   74 14                   je     400888 <frame_dummy+0x28>
  400874:   55                      push   %rbp
  400875:   bf e8 0d 60 00          mov    $0x600de8,%edi
  40087a:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40087d:   ff d0                   callq  *%rax
  40087f:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  400880:   e9 7b ff ff ff          jmpq   400800 <register_tm_clones>
  400885:   0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)
  400888:   e9 73 ff ff ff          jmpq   400800 <register_tm_clones>
  40088d:   90                      nop
  40088e:   90                      nop
  40088f:   90                      nop

0000000000400890 <main>:
  400890:   55                      push   %rbp
  400891:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400894:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400899:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  40089a:   c3                      retq   

000000000040089b <_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii>:
  40089b:   55                      push   %rbp
  40089c:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40089f:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
  4008a3:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
  4008a6:   89 75 f8                mov    %esi,-0x8(%rbp)
  4008a9:   83 7d fc 01             cmpl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
  4008ad:   75 27                   jne    4008d6 <_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii+0x3b>
  4008af:   81 7d f8 ff ff 00 00    cmpl   $0xffff,-0x8(%rbp)
  4008b6:   75 1e                   jne    4008d6 <_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii+0x3b>
  4008b8:   bf 34 10 60 00          mov    $0x601034,%edi
  4008bd:   e8 7e fe ff ff          callq  400740 <_ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev@plt>
  4008c2:   ba 28 10 60 00          mov    $0x601028,%edx
  4008c7:   be 34 10 60 00          mov    $0x601034,%esi
  4008cc:   bf 70 07 40 00          mov    $0x400770,%edi
  4008d1:   e8 8a fe ff ff          callq  400760 <__cxa_atexit@plt>
  4008d6:   c9                      leaveq 
  4008d7:   c3                      retq   

00000000004008d8 <_GLOBAL__sub_I_main>:
  4008d8:   55                      push   %rbp
  4008d9:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4008dc:   be ff ff 00 00          mov    $0xffff,%esi
  4008e1:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
  4008e6:   e8 b0 ff ff ff          callq  40089b <_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii>
  4008eb:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  4008ec:   c3                      retq   
  4008ed:   90                      nop
  4008ee:   90                      nop
  4008ef:   90                      nop

00000000004008f0 <__libc_csu_init>:
  4008f0:   48 89 6c 24 d8          mov    %rbp,-0x28(%rsp)
  4008f5:   4c 89 64 24 e0          mov    %r12,-0x20(%rsp)
  4008fa:   48 8d 2d df 04 20 00    lea    0x2004df(%rip),%rbp        # 600de0 <__init_array_end>
  400901:   4c 8d 25 c8 04 20 00    lea    0x2004c8(%rip),%r12        # 600dd0 <__frame_dummy_init_array_entry>
  400908:   4c 89 6c 24 e8          mov    %r13,-0x18(%rsp)
  40090d:   4c 89 74 24 f0          mov    %r14,-0x10(%rsp)
  400912:   4c 89 7c 24 f8          mov    %r15,-0x8(%rsp)
  400917:   48 89 5c 24 d0          mov    %rbx,-0x30(%rsp)
  40091c:   48 83 ec 38             sub    $0x38,%rsp
  400920:   4c 29 e5                sub    %r12,%rbp
  400923:   41 89 fd                mov    %edi,%r13d
  400926:   49 89 f6                mov    %rsi,%r14
  400929:   48 c1 fd 03             sar    $0x3,%rbp
  40092d:   49 89 d7                mov    %rdx,%r15
  400930:   e8 e3 fd ff ff          callq  400718 <_init>
  400935:   48 85 ed                test   %rbp,%rbp
  400938:   74 1c                   je     400956 <__libc_csu_init+0x66>
  40093a:   31 db                   xor    %ebx,%ebx
  40093c:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
  400940:   4c 89 fa                mov    %r15,%rdx
  400943:   4c 89 f6                mov    %r14,%rsi
  400946:   44 89 ef                mov    %r13d,%edi
  400949:   41 ff 14 dc             callq  *(%r12,%rbx,8)
  40094d:   48 83 c3 01             add    $0x1,%rbx
  400951:   48 39 eb                cmp    %rbp,%rbx
  400954:   75 ea                   jne    400940 <__libc_csu_init+0x50>
  400956:   48 8b 5c 24 08          mov    0x8(%rsp),%rbx
  40095b:   48 8b 6c 24 10          mov    0x10(%rsp),%rbp
  400960:   4c 8b 64 24 18          mov    0x18(%rsp),%r12
  400965:   4c 8b 6c 24 20          mov    0x20(%rsp),%r13
  40096a:   4c 8b 74 24 28          mov    0x28(%rsp),%r14
  40096f:   4c 8b 7c 24 30          mov    0x30(%rsp),%r15
  400974:   48 83 c4 38             add    $0x38,%rsp
  400978:   c3                      retq   
  400979:   0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)

0000000000400980 <__libc_csu_fini>:
  400980:   f3 c3                   repz retq 
  400982:   90                      nop
  400983:   90                      nop

Disassembly of section .fini:

0000000000400984 <_fini>:
  400984:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  400988:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  40098c:   c3                      retq
```

For completeness, I'm using:
Ubuntu:  12.04
Valgrind:  3.10.1 <strike>3.7.0</strike>
g++: 4.8.1

NB: As a side note, this does not happen when I include other headers such as `<fstream>` or `<cmath>`.

Comment: ubuntu 14.04, g++ 4.8.2, valgrind 3.10.0 and no leaks! Probably needs valgrind upgrade.

Comment: You're ahead of me on all fronts!  I wonder which update fixed it.  Unfortunately I can't update Ubuntu at the moment.

Comment: You should probably paste the full valgrind output. Also make sure you run with --leak-check=full and --track-origins=yes for better information

Comment: @mjs -- Added the full valgrind output.  Adding --show-reachable=yes added a little extra information.  I don't quite follow, but it almost looks like it's something that *valgrind* allotted, rather than something my program did.  Is that possible?

Comment: @doqtor -- Same result even after updating valgrind.  Curiouser and curiouser...

Comment: @PyNewb Did you build your test program with `-pg` or other options?

Comment: No leak is shown by the leak sanitizer of gcc/clang (`-fsanitize=leak`)

Comment: Hi PyNewb, I have the same problem on my arch linux system. Exactly the same number of bytes in 1 block, both for a trivial test case like your show, and a larger application which was memory leak free recently. Very curious indeed!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It's Valgrind's fault. First, `-fsanitize=leak` does not show anything. Second, Valgrind itself [states](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.reports) that:

> First of all: relax, it's probably not a bug, but a feature. Many
>   implementations of the C++ standard libraries use their own memory
>   pool allocators. Memory for quite a number of destructed objects is
>   not immediately freed and given back to the OS, but kept in the
>   pool(s) for later re-use. The fact that the pools are not freed at the
>   exit of the program cause Valgrind to report this memory as still
>   reachable. The behaviour not to free pools at the exit could be called
>   a bug of the library though.
>
> Using GCC, you can force the STL to use malloc and to free memory as
>   soon as possible by globally disabling memory caching. Beware! Doing
>   so will probably slow down your program, sometimes drastically.
>
> With GCC 2.91, 2.95, 3.0 and 3.1, compile all source using the STL
>   with -D__USE_MALLOC. Beware! This was removed from GCC starting with
>   version 3.3.
>
> With GCC 3.2.2 and later, you should export the environment variable
>   GLIBCPP_FORCE_NEW before running your program.
>
> With GCC 3.4 and later, that variable has changed name to
>   GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW.
>
> [...]

I guess those alleged memory pools are freed *after* program's termination,  in the so-called start-up code that calls `main`, among the other settings. Internal functions defined outside user's code should be treated as if they didn't exist, that's why Valgrind can't (and shouldn't) see further frees.

Answer (score 8):

Consider the following trivial include file:

```
#ifndef TRIVIAL_INCLUDE_FILE
#define TRIVIAL_INCLUDE_FILE
static int *x = new int (0);
#endif
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the question was severely edited from the form that I answered. The original question was, "*I'd just like to understand how simply including a standard library header could cause a still reachable warning, when none of the objects from that library were allocated in the program itself.*" The example code answers that question.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Unfortunately I was able to reproduce the exact same issue without including any headers.

Comment: What exactly is this supposed to do? Compiling with g++ gives me `error: expected type-specifier before ‘x’`

Answer (score 7):

For gcc 6 and higher, a related bug fix arrived:

- [Bug report: "Warning about "still reachable" memory when using libstdc++ from gcc 5"](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=345307)
- [Discussion on the Arch Linux bug tracker](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/45051)

With gcc 5, you can also get the same warning without including `iostream`.

So, if you see a similar warning referring to `dl-init.c` and you are using gcc 5, consider upgrading to a newer version (gcc >=6), or try to compile with clang.

Comment: I have the exact same error above with libstdc++.so.6.0.28, so it might need to be more new than 6

Comment: Using Valgrind-3.14.0.SVN and g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, I got `total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 72,704 bytes allocated`, so I can confirm _no leakage_ (WSL1).

Comment: ubuntu 16.04, apt provided valgrind (3.11.0), gcc 5.5, reports no leak, but clang-8.0 (apt provided) or even clang-11.0 (manually downloaded) still reports `dl-init.c` leak.