# std::cout causes memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have a very simple C++ program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "HI" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I compile this on a Mac with the command `c++ --std=c++11 leak.cpp`.

When I debug this with `valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out`, I get the following output:

```
==2187== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2187==     in use at exit: 38,906 bytes in 429 blocks
==2187==   total heap usage: 508 allocs, 79 frees, 45,074 bytes allocated
==2187== 
==2187== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2187==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2187==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2187==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2187==    still reachable: 4,096 bytes in 1 blocks
==2187==         suppressed: 34,810 bytes in 428 blocks
==2187== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==2187== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
```

Turns out there are 4096 bytes that are "still reachable". If I remove the `cout` statement then there are no more "still reachable" bytes.

Why is it the case that outputting to `std::cout` causes a memory leak?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30376601/valgrind-memory-still-reachable-with-trivial-program-using-iostream) ?

Answer (score 3):

It could be a false positive in the leak report. Valgrind can only be so clever; your standard library implementation is taking certain liberties that Valgrind doesn't have a special case for.

I'd be more worried about figuring out why this tiny program is performing 508 allocations, to a total of 45,074 bytes.

Comment: Still reachable is not a leak.

Comment: Probably some debugging structures