# Memory leak detected by valgrind, but cannot find line where I forget to free

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

Here is simplified version of the code, I deleted everything that doesn't concern the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#define N 3

int main() {

    int *input;
    int **cl;

    input = new int[N];
    cl = new int*[N];
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cl[i] = new int[N];
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        delete[] cl[i];
    }
    delete[] cl;
    delete[] input;

    return 0;
}
```

And the valgrind output:

```
==5782== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5782==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==5782==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 5 frees, 72,776 bytes allocated
==5782== 
==5782== 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==5782==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5782==    by 0x4EC3EFF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==5782==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==5782==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==5782==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==5782==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==5782== 
==5782== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5782==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5782==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5782==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5782==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==5782==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5782== 
==5782== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5782== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I just started to learn C++, maybe there is some stupid error that I cannot see.

I know I should also check for example if there was no "out of memory" error when allocating, but I ignore it so that code is more clear. I also know I could use e.g. vector and don't care for the allocation, but I'm still concerned what I do wrong.

Comment: Eventually you will learn `c++` and not have to deal with this..

Comment: Looks correct but this is why manual memory management is best avoided if you can.

Comment: @sashoalm new and delete typcally just wrap malloc and free.

Comment: Tools like valgrind will stick you with your nose into it (like puppy education).

Comment: Can you show the valgrind report?

Comment: BTW, I don't see a leak.

Comment: _@smutnyjoe_ Why are you doing [dynamic memory management](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) on your own? I don't see a need for that.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, but OP using them interchangeably is a bad sign.

Comment: std::vector is your friend.  Make a vector of vectors and all your memory issues go away.

Comment: @sashoalm Well if valgrind really shows mallocs and frees you can't blame him.  not sure if it does though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If OP wants to learn the basics of dynamic memory allocation, this is a good way to do it. In the industry, there are moments where you have to deal with older C++ code and have to know how it works. This is no place to question the intent of OP.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It could be an college assignment. He isn't to blame for the fact that many professors stopped after C++98.

Comment: Run the check with `--leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all` and see if this post answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30376601/valgrind-memory-still-reachable-with-trivial-program-using-iostream

Comment: @lordjohncena _"This is no place to question the intent of OP."_ May be they just don't know better yet. I want to help them out with that.

Comment: The OP could have simply done one allocation and deallocation, and see if the ValGrind error still occurred.  Then incrementally add allocations / deallocations until the error appears.  Obviously divide and conquer approaches to solving issues isn't taught in schools these days.

Comment: @AdrianJałoszewski Yes, could be. You may read here in which cases I think such stuff is [bad assignments](http://dev-jungle.blogspot.de/2015/02/i-have-dream-im-dreaming-of-so-called-c.html).

Comment: Wait - 12 mallocs?
your code has 2xn + 3 new's.  That's an odd number of new's you call, and 11 would mean that n == 4

Perhaps you can post the entire valgrind output?

Comment: I would be more concerned with if any blocks were lost rather than if allocs and frees are equivalent. If no blocks were leaked then you're probably fine.

Comment: To all: I am very sorry. I wanted to post a question too fast, and I see that I didn't explain correctly the problem or paste valgrind output. You can assume that n = 3 (That's why 12 mallocs). I know C and can do mallocs and frees manually (btw then there are no memory leaks when i do it manually). I now learn C++ and for the first time I tried to create and destruct array with "new" and "delete[]". I'll edit my question when i am back at home. For now, I can only add that valgrind said that the one block I lost was still reachable.

Comment: @smutnyjoe In C++ it is good practice to do resource management with constructors and destructors. That is exactly what I do in my answer with `std::vector`. The vector allocates memory in the constructor, that I use (there are others as well) and the destructor frees it again. It will be called at the end of the scope of the vector.

Comment: @cdonat Thank you for your answer (and thank everyone for your comments). Vector could be useful and easier to implement, I admit. However, can you explain me why valgrind shows one less free than the number of mallocs (see my edited post)

Answer (score 1):

C++ provides you with tools, that encapsulate memory management for you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    // read the size for the vectors
    int n;
    std::cin >> n >> '\n';

    // allocate vector with n elements
    auto input = std::vector<int>{n};

    // read the elements
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cin >> std::setw(1) >> input[i];
    }
    // print them
    for(const auto& d : input) {
        std::cout << d << std::endl;
    }

    // allocate the vectors and store 1 in each field.
    auto Cl = std::vector<std::vector<int>>{n, std::vector<int>{n, 1}};
    auto Cr = std::vector<std::vector<int>>{n, std::vector<int>{n, 1}};

    return 0;

    // will safely release all the memory here.
}
```

This looks a lot more like C++, and less like C. The vectors will handle all the memory management automatically for you.

Beware: I have not tested this code, so it will probably contain some bugs. I assume C++11 syntax, but it should be easy to change the code to older C++ syntax as well.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've added the valgrind output it's clearly the same issue as the one that has an answer here: [Valgrind: Memory still reachable with trivial program using <iostream>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30376601/valgrind-memory-still-reachable-with-trivial-program-using-iostream)

The short story is that it's not your code that causes that report. You can remove everything from `main()` and just return and valgrind will still give you that leak.

Read the accepted answer on that question for the explanation.