# How to see heap dynamicly during execution C++

Tags: c++, debugging, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I made a C++ application and I currently test it for memory leaks.

On g++ 7.2.0 it has no leaks

[image]

but on g++ 5.4.0 it does.

[image]

I have some classes (dynamic data structures) are initialized and used but this seems to be irrelevant to the leak as it has the same size even when the data structures are way bigger or always empty until the end.

How can I see where these 72,704 bytes are allocated so i can free them?

Any help/ideas are welcome.

I can provide the code if needed.

Comment: probably in libc.

Comment: "Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory"

Comment: Either libc or the C++ library, but unlikely to be yours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this specific case, you can't as its a gcc bug that has (as you noticed) been fixed: [Valgrind: Memory still reachable with trivial program using <iostream>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30376601/valgrind-memory-still-reachable-with-trivial-program-using-iostream)

Should you actually want to investigate your heap usage, you could use valgrinds heap profiler: massif http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html

Comment: The exact same 72704 bytes is a bit of a giveaway.

Comment: @MSalters That's true, thank god it is not my fault. I was frustrated that I could not find where it was.