# Unable to figure out memory leak in my code

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, singleton, valgrind

I have written following code and its working fine, but when I run valgrind to check for leaks then I get a big leak. Don't know what I am doing wrong.

Anyone please help me to understand what I am doing wrong ?

MY SINGLETON CLASS:

Header: SampleClass.h

```
#ifndef SAMPLECLASS_H
#define SAMPLECLASS_H

    struct sqlite3;

    class SampleClass
    {
        private:
        static SampleClass *m_pHandle;
        sqlite3 *m_pSqlDb;

        public:
        static SampleClass* getHandle() { 
            if (!m_pHandle)
            {
                m_pHandle = new SampleClass();
            } 
            return m_pHandle; 
        }

        static void deleteHandle()
        {
            delete m_pHandle;
            m_pHandle = nullptr;
        }
        void setDatabase(const sqlite3 *psqldb)
        {
            if (psqldb)
            {
            m_pSqlDb = const_cast<sqlite3*>(psqldb);
            }
            else { 
                // print error 
            }
        }

        private:
        SampleClass() : m_pSqlDb(nullptr) {}
        ~SampleClass() { m_pSqlDb = nullptr; }

        SampleClass(const SampleClass&) = delete;
        SampleClass& operator=(const SampleClass&) = delete;
        SampleClass(SampleClass&&) = delete;
        SampleClass& operator=(SampleClass&&) = delete;

    };

    #endif // SAMPLECLASS_H
```

Implementaion: SampleClass.cpp

```
#include "SampleClass.h"

    SampleClass* SampleClass::m_pHandle = nullptr;
```

MY DRIVER PROGRAM: Test.cpp

```
#include "SampleClass.h"
#include <sqlite3.h>

int main()
{
    sqlite3 *mydb;
    const int retStatus = sqlite3_open_v2("./CPMDB_M100.db", &mydb, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, nullptr);

    SampleClass::getHandle()->setDatabase(mydb);

    SampleClass::deleteHandle();

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting leak summary like below in my actual implementation.

```
> LEAK SUMMARY:
> ==32074==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==32074==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==32074==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==32074==    still reachable: 82,680 bytes in 75 blocks
> ==32074==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
> ==32074==                         length64           : 9,968 bytes in 73 blocks
```

If I remove the deleteHandle() call in main() then all those lost blocks bytes goes under "still reachable" category.

```
LEAK SUMMARY:
==32095==    definitely lost: 872 bytes in 1 blocks
==32095==    indirectly lost: 9,016 bytes in 71 blocks
==32095==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==32095==    still reachable: 72,784 bytes in 2 blocks
==32095==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==32095==                         length64           : 80 bytes in 1 blocks
```

Commands to compile:

```
g++ -c -std=gnu++11 Test.cpp
g++ -c -std=gnu++11 SampleClass.cpp
g++ -o Test Test.o SampleClass.o -L/usr/include -lsqlite3
```

Thanks

Comment: shouldn't your deleteHandle() function set the handle to null then delete it?

Comment: then he definitely has a memory leak. Did you try to null the pointers to the db?

Comment: What is `m_pHandle`? Did you mean `m_handle` ? Show us the actual source code you are compiling.

Comment: OK deleting comments and recommending instead that you familiarize yourself with and start observing [RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii). You're doomed to fumbling around with inferior solutions until you do.

Comment: @birdfreeyahoo I have already null the pointer in destructor.

Comment: @GauravSehgal Yes, I meant m_pHandle. Let me give you full working code then

Comment: @SharpIncTechAndProgramming if you first set the handler to null then you would loose the memory address on which you want to call delete. So the current order is the correct one not the one you suggested.

Comment: @SharpIncTechAndProgramming Added full source code and results. Plz take a look and let me know what is wrong. Thanks

Comment: @GauravSehgal Added full source code and results. Plz take a look and let me know what is wrong. Thanks

Comment: @birdfreeyahoo Added full source code and results. Plz take a look and let me know what is wrong. Thanks

Comment: null the sqldb pointer in the class and in the main function. Also close the db before.

Comment: When you run valgrind you should get an "invite" for more information on the leaks that can help you track down exactly what is getting lost.

Comment: Have this in mind also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30376601/valgrind-memory-still-reachable-with-trivial-program-using-iostream

Comment: I've rollbacked your last edit: please find your solution in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52713305/revisions) and post it as an answer of its own, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the SQL database with `sqlite3_close_v2`.

Comment: I forgot to add it, but actual code had this but still did not work. I have figured out the actual reason. Thanks